# Paperclip Added - Now Model does Not Accept Updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, paperclip

Currently I have a model 'Locations' that has an image upload field added to the form. When I go, to lets say" update one the existing locations or even add a new one, it will upload the image correctly and display it, but will not save any of the input fields.

If I remove the upload photo field on the form and do not require it, then everything updates and saves correctly. So having an issue when a image is present, it saving the image but not the rest of the fields.

Any suggestions on why this might be happening?

Locations.rb

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :region
  has_many :spots


  validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

   has_attached_file :photo,
                :styles => { :thumb => "150x150#", :medium => "200x200#"},
                :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
                :s3_domain_url => "adsimgstore.s3.amazonaws.com",
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml"),
                :bucket => 'adsimgstore',
                :s3_permissions => :public_read,
                :convert_options => { :all => "-auto-orient" }


   attr_accessible :locations, :photo, :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type, :photo_file_size,     :photo_updated_at
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for (@location), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @location.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@location.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this location from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @location.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :network_id %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :network_id %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :region_id %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :region_id %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :spot_duration %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :spot_duration %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :frequency %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :frequency %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :screen_count %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :screen_count %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :ad_size %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :ad_size %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :ad_type %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :ad_type %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :impressions %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :impressions %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :rate_card %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :rate_card %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <td><%= image_tag @location.photo.url(:thumb) %></td>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you copy the model and the form?

Comment: Updated Post - Also note that the :photo field was "added" at a later date to the model via Paperclip. So not sure if the current tables are not associating themselves with :photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to comment the line

```
   attr_accessible :locations, :photo, :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type, :photo_file_size,     :photo_updated_at
```